# is that correct to use "local residents" in the below sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

I'd like to say

> they only provide their services **to people in the same country that
> their company is located**.

Is that correct to use "local residents" instead of above sentence?

> they only provide their services to **local residents**.

Comment: "local residents" is grammatically correct, but I don't think it means what you are trying to say.  "Local" means "nearby", but you want to say "anyone in the same country", right?  Someone in California is in the same country as someone in New York, but they are definitely not "local" to each other.

Comment: thank for your answer. that's right. i want to say "anyone in the same country".
but I'd like to know if there's any better and shorter sentence than the first one?